# Google Apps Script ContentService.createTextOutput is not sending number values

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to send a simple JSON response but ContentService.createTextOutput seems to be stripping the number values and replacing with null. Console.log shows the correct output from JSON.stringify. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
function doPost(e) {
  let response = {};
  console.log(e);
  switch(e.parameter.action){
    case 'request':
      response = e;
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(response)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    case 'price':
      response = calculatePrice(e);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(response)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    case 'default':
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify('Error: Action not found')).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}

function calculatePrice(request){
  const { date, num_people, num_guest } = request.parameter;
  const day = getDay(date);
  let price = 0;
  let location = '';

  if(day == "Tuesday" || day == "Wednesday" || day == "Friday" || day == "Sunday"){
    location = "London";
    price = 123;
  } else {
    location = "Newcastle";
    price = 567;
  }
  const people_total = num_people * price; 
  const guest_total = num_guest * 1250;
  const total_price = people_total + guest_total;
  const total_deposit = total_price * 0.2;

  const response = {
    day,
    location,
    total_price,
    total_deposit,
  }

  return response;
}

function getDay(date){
  const dayNames = ["Sunday","Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  const d = new Date(date);
  const day = d.getDay();
  return dayNames[day];
}
```

I should be getting:

{"day":"Thursday","location":"Newcastle","total_price":2384,"total_deposit":476.8}

But when testing with postman POST Request: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzzugQbaDk1WKhue58xmDp30BZ7yNYBsPmGcQ0jTZDYzCjN8j20_amtWSD4WJUJCt0IwA/exec?action=price&date=01-18-2024&people_total=2&guest_total=1

I get this result:

{
"day": "Thursday",
"location": "Newcastle",
"total_price": null,
"total_deposit": null
}

Comment: About `Console.log shows the correct output from JSON.stringify`, in your showing script, I cannot find it. I apologize for this situation. Where did you put it? And, how did you run the script? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Thanks Tanaike. I have included the console.log statement now and a description of the outputs I am expecting/getting.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `But when testing with postman I am getting:`, from your updated question, I couldn't understand the details of the request by postman. Can I ask you about the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue?

Comment: Updated with the POST request

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your updated question, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- From your showing script and request `POST https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec?action=price&date=01-18-2024&people_total=2&guest_total=1`, I think that in your request, the query parameter is `action=price&date=01-18-2024&people_total=2&guest_total=1`. In this case, the event object `e` has `{ parameter: { action: "price", date: "01-18-2024", "people_total": "2", "guest_total": "1" } }`. But, in your script, `people_total` and `guest_total` are not used. At `const { date, num_people, num_guest } = request.parameter;`, `num_people` and `num_guest` are used. I guess that this might be the reason for your current issue.

If you want to use your showing script, please request with the following URL.

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzzugQbaDk1WKhue58xmDp30BZ7yNYBsPmGcQ0jTZDYzCjN8j20_amtWSD4WJUJCt0IwA/exec?action=price&date=01-18-2024&num_people=2&num_guest=1
```

In this modification, the query parameters of `people_total` and `guest_total` were modified to `num_people` and `num_guest`, respectively.

As a test, when I tested the following curl command,

```bash
$ curl -L -d "" "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzzugQbaDk1WKhue58xmDp30BZ7yNYBsPmGcQ0jTZDYzCjN8j20_amtWSD4WJUJCt0IwA/exec?action=price&date=01-18-2024&num_people=2&num_guest=1"
```

the following result is obtained.

```
{"day":"Thursday","location":"Newcastle","total_price":2384,"total_deposit":476.8}
```

It seems that this result is your expected value.

Comment: ‍♂️ Yes you are right. Thank you Tanaike-san!

Comment: @Matt Nethaway About `Yes you are right. Thank you Tanaike-san!`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer